# Replace all instances of something in Excel formulas in the entire book using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In every formula of every cell of every sheet, the entire book, I want to replace part of the formula string, changing all "+" to "-", is there an easy way to do this in VBA if I have a particular workbook object `xlWb`?

I am trying:

```
xlWb.Cells.Replace What:="+", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

but get "Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: You will need to loop the worksheets in xlWb and do that on each.

Comment: I would first replace "=" with "xyza" then replace + with - and then replace xyza with =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workbook has not cells, only worksheets have. This causes your runtime error. Your Replace-command itself looks okay to me.

Simply loop over all the worksheets of your workbook should do the trick:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In xlWb.Worksheets
    ws.Cells.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="+", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
        , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Next
```

(If I where you, I would make a backup of the workbook before running the macro...)